# How can I ensure that some tasks are executed as soon as possible when using rayon?

Tags: multithreading, rust, scheduler, rayon

#### Context

Imagine that I am writing a game that uses rayon to execute main gameplay loop.

Sometimes, I need to spawn long-running tasks which can themselves be parallelized (e.g. saving and loading game, or loading and generating a level, or parsing and preparing assets, compiling shaders).

I would like to make those tasks utilise as much threads possible while keeping at least 1 or maybe 2 threads for main gameplay loop to avoid complete unresponsiveness for users (though I don't mind losing some FPS due to lack of parallelization).

Main loop is running inside rayon threadpool because I found out that this improves latency between spawning some tasks and continuing after their finish.

#### The problem

I don't see how can I make rayon threadpool reserve some threads for main loop. As I see, it is completely possible for tasks from background job to fill job queues for all threads so they would run them while main loop tasks would do nothing.

#### My current solution and question

I currently decided to create a temporary threadpool for background tasks which would have higher thread priority (set by OS API) but less threads than main pool (e.g. num_cores - 1 ). Since OS would prioritise background pool threads over main pool, background tasks would get more CPU time while still allowing main loop to progress using single left-out core. After task is done, I would be able to just drop background pool so OS would reclaim those threads.

Can this task be solved somehow better?
I want something like possibility to spawn tasks in rayon that allowed to run only on some threads from pool, or prioritization for some tasks inside rayon itself.